# Why is "Visible Light" in the middle of the spectrum and not at an end?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, biophysics, vision

I realize that the spectrum is man-made, and "visible" is a human-relative term. However, the scale is based on objectives, such as frequency and wavelength, and "visible" light is objectively unique in that it wholly absorbed by solid/opaque objects. EM waves on *either* side of it can pass through intervening media (albeit to different degrees). Is there a specific reason why the "colored" wavelengths are uniquely blocked by objects?

Comment: ""visible" light is objectively unique in that it wholly absorbed by solid/opaque objects. " is not true in that other parts of the electromagnetic spectrum are wholly absorbed by solid objects. Try getting UV through a brick wall.

Comment: Isn't UV considered the very upper limit of the Visible section (just like IR is the lower limit)? Even if we "can't see them" it seems like that specific region is unique (maybe I'm wrong). If you go either way from there, very high energy or high wave lengths, it seems that objects become less of an issue

Comment: Try tv/radio waves through salt water.

Comment: I would say that we define "opaque objects" as those which block visible light. But there are also objects that are e.g. "opaque in the UV".

Comment: Light in the visible range can pass through quartz glass, UV light can't. Light in the visible range can more or less pass through a lead grid, microwaves can't. Light in the visible range *can't* pass through a brick wall, infrared radiation can. There is a as such no difference between light/radiation in any part of the spectrum. Some eyes are just developed to see certain parts of it - many bugs can see a larger or shifted range as far as I know. The only unique thing about light in the visible range is that humans happen to be able to see it.

Comment: Just for the record, I find the terms "beginning" and "end" of the spectrum to be somewhat confusing.  You can have frequencies ranging from incredibly low to incredibly high, we just choose a "spectrum" that shows frequencies we are familiar with and experience (there are likely physical limits due to some constraints at very small/large scales, but for the most part you can at least mathematically represent any frequency) a frequency spectrum has no beginning or end beyond where you choose to be cutoff points.

Comment: Just for the record, we can't actually see light. Our retina detects light which causes our brain to create images in the optic centre. It's these images we see. The correct term is image causing light. Not visible light.

Comment: It's obviously evolution. Physicists think it's all physics. Chemists would say because when you have chemical reactions that's what's emitted. It's the freqs that are useful for us to see the objects we need to see, i.e., massive ones. I guess if we were nocturnal we'd see more IR And if we were in a neutron star maybe we'd see whatever EM freqs might hover around. It's not in the middle of the spectrum, it's in the middle or close to the spectra of the Sun, which is our daylight source. Btw our eyes evolved for seeing in water as fish or amphibian, and I've read were not optimal on land

Comment: X-Rays don't go through bone. That's why x-ray scans work

Comment: @zanescheepers Just for the record, we can actually see light. What you described with our retinas and optic centre of the brain is the process by which we see something. The usage of the word is intended to describe the process of sensing light as "seeing" it. Thus, by necessity of definition, whatever we do with our eyes regarding light is seeing light. The ability of there to be hallucinations that don't correspond to any stimulation of optic nerves does not make our interaction with light any less worthy of the verb "to see".

Comment: @jim https://books.google.co.za/books?dq=do+we+see+or+feel+photons%3F&hl=en&id=rPNHAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA109&ots=z-SPeSNkqN&pg=PA109&sa=X&sig=DNk__1lCk-GcaYSeMXSSoBeUsFs&source=bl&ved=0ahUKEwiytpf1m43TAhWBCMAKHZ9vAUEQ6AEIQjAH#v=onepage&q=do%20we%20see%20or%20feel%20photons%3F&f=false read page 108 to 109

Comment: @zanescheepers saying we can't make a passive observation of a photon isn't at all the same as saying we can't "see" a photon. Having read the pages you reference, I'd say the author wasn't thinking things through enough. The argument presented is more of an argument for why one can't "see" a bus than it is a photon. But all this is moot because the usage of "to see" is not going to change among the population. And how a word is used defines its meaning. I see light with my eyes. Whatever process that takes is irrelevant, the word is defined to always be valid in this context.

Comment: @jim that's possible. But it's more probable that these professors thought these things through more than other people http://www.trincoll.edu/depts/ecopsyc/perils/folder5/light.html

Answer (score 2):

I feel like Captain Obvious, but you seem to have it backwards.

Different objects (continuous media, conducting grids, whatnot) have transmission and absorbtion spectra, that is, they transmit various parts of the electromagnetic spectrum to different degrees. Our eyes, on the other hand, detect only a part of the radiation -- that part is what we *call* visible light, and the objects that block that light are (commonly) *called* opaque. Of course, opaque objects (for visible light) may be transparent to other frequencies (e.g. radio waves through walls), and transparent objects may be opaque to other radiation (e.g. UV through glass).

This is different from being solid: glass and bricks are solid, water and black ink are liquid, yet one of each transmits visible light and one doesn't.